# Considering the function $g(x) = e^{-x}, x>0$ and $g(-x) = -g(x)$. I am trying to find the Fourier integral representation of $g(x)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Considering the function $g(x) = e^{-x}, x>0$ and $g(-x) = -g(x)$. I am trying to find the Fourier integral representation of $g(x)$.

I am looking for some clarification on the progress I have made below to see if I am on the correct path before I begin integrating.

So from the question, $g(-x) = -g(x)$ meaning $g(x)$ is an odd function. Then,

$$F(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-j\omega x}dx$$

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(\omega)e^{j\omega x}d\omega$$

Expand the first formula yielding

$F(\omega)=A(\omega)+jB(\omega)$

where, $A(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\cos(\omega x)dx$, 
$B(\omega)=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\sin(\omega x)dx$

Since $g(x)$ is an odd function, $A(\omega)=0$. Then now what I have to do is calculate $B(\omega)$

$$B(\omega)=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\sin(\omega x)dx=-2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\sin(\omega x)dx$$

So I am wondering if I have taken the correct steps, thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting to do a Fourier series for a function on a bounded interval? Or a Fourier transform for a function on all of $\mathbb{R}$? those are two different things.

Comment: I was asked for the fourier integral representation but I think a transform works

Comment: would you know how to do this?

Comment: In another post, we discussed that the cosine Fourier coefficients of an odd function will vanish, and the sine Fourier coefficients of an even function will vanish. None of that applies to a Fourier transform. In your question you wrote the Fourier transform, but it soudns like you want a Fourier series? So it's not clear? What is the domain of $g(x)$?

Comment: @ziggurism I am a little confused by this question, I thought x>0

Comment: yes it must be a fourier series then

Comment: a function with domain $x>0$ is neither even nor odd... and the equation $g(-x)=-g(x)$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: well then, I am not quite sure what to do at all

Comment: I think you should find out what your question is

Comment: me too, thanks for your help anyways!

Comment: The question makes sense to me. This function is defined as 
$$ g(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-x}, & x > 0 \\ -e^x, & x < 0 \end{cases}$$

The $g(-x) = -g(x)$ is the definition for negative $x$, implying an odd function on $\mathbb{R}$. This also means you want a Fourier transform, not Fourier series.

Comment: Also @ziggurism, "Fourier integral representation" is related to the Fourier transform, but instead of just finding the transform, the original function is rewritten as an integral form. It's like the Fourier series, but the Fourier coefficients are treated as continuous functions.

Comment: @Dylan that's the second time today that you've been able to understand a question that I could not

Comment: @ziggurism would I need to integrate that integral he has shown below?

Comment: @user104 yes I would imagine so. You already arrived at this integral yourself in the question, though I wonder why yours has a minus sign that Dylan's lacks.

Comment: Details like the normalization constant, the integral limits and the signs will depend on which particular Fourier integral is being used. This has never been consistent, and I only provided a rough idea of what it looks like in my answer. It's up to OP to determine explicitly how the integral forms are defined

Answer (score 2):

I see from the comments that the wording may have confused you. $g(x)$ is defined to be the odd extension of $e^{-x}$ on the entire real line. This means its Fourier representation is a sine integral

$$ g(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} B(\omega) \sin (\omega x) \ d\omega $$

where

$$ B(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) \sin(\omega x) \ dx = -\int_{-\infty}^0 e^x \sin (\omega x) + \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} \sin (\omega x) \ dx \\
= 2\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x} \sin (\omega x) \ dx$$

Comment: thanks so much for your post, and this will be the final answer? or do I need to integrate that?

Comment: $$2\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x}sin(wx)dx = \frac{2w}{w^2+1}$$ would this be the final answer?

Comment: Looks right to me